# How to find file path to load table?

Tags: r, file, path

I downloaded a .csv file and saved it on my desktop. Now, to work with it, I am supposed to use the `read.table()` or `read.csv()` functions to load the file into R. How do I find the file path for input into a line like this:

```
yy_2 <- read.csv(file =....., header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I use a MacBook Pro, if that helps.

Comment: You can use `getwd()` (to find the current path of the R process) or `file.choose()` to interactively find the file (it will return a `character` of the full path to the file). If you don't want to learn from this and/or do it with different files all the time, then you can short-circuit it with `read.csv(file.choose(), ...)`, though it gets tiresome if you have to read in the same file multiple times.

Comment: Great! I also found out how to copy the file path name directly by a two-finger click while holding the Option key.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, this is most likely to be

```
fdir <- file.path("~/Desktop")
```

(`~` is Unix shorthand for your home directory.) You can try `list.files(fdir)` to see if the files are there.  Alternately you could try `file.choose()` as suggested in comments above, although that can only select a file, not a directory; this seems to be a long-standing gap in R (see e.g. [this mailing list post from 2012](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2012-November/009741.html), which suggests `dirname(file.choose())` or this function:

```
choose.dir <- function() {
    system("osascript -e 'tell app \"R\" to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt \"Choose Folder:\")' > /tmp/R_folder",
            intern = FALSE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
    p <- system("cat /tmp/R_folder && rm -f /tmp/R_folder", intern = TRUE)
    return(ifelse(length(p), p, NA))
}
```

which appears to crash RStudio (!) but works in the R console on MacOS for me ...